# Solving a profit maximization with Cobb-Douglas production function

Tags: equation-solving, mathematical-optimization

I'm considering a typical profit-maximization problem:

\begin{equation} \label{optimization1}
\begin{aligned}
& \underset{K,L}{\text{max}}
& & P Y - r K - w L \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

where $r$ is the interest rate and $w$ is the wage rate.

The production function can be Cobb-Douglas,

$Y=AK^{\alpha}L^{\beta}$

where $0\leq \alpha \leq 1$ and $0\leq \beta \leq 1$. Or it can be a CES production function.

I would like to find the solution for $K$ and $L$ in either case of production function.

My code in the case of Cobb-Douglas, for example, is:

```
Y = A k^a L^b;
PROF = P Y - r k - w L;
z1 = D[PROF, k];
z2 = D[PROF, L];
Simplify[Solve[{z1 == 0, z2 == 0}, {k, L}], {0 <= a <= 1 && 0 <= b <= 1 && 
A > 0 && k > 0 && L > 0 && P > 0 && r > 0 && w > 0 && PROF > 0}]
```

And I get a very weird solution as follows.
[image]

Can anyone help in finding what went wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Why are you so convinced that anything went wrong? However, you have inequality constraints on `k` and `L`, so ypu need to solve the full set of [KKT conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush–Kuhn–Tucker_conditions). And those can usually only be solved when numerical values for all parameters are given.

Comment: @Henrik: You can sense that the solution is weird once you solve it manually and compare. (In fact, it is easy to find on the internet a note that describes the process of solving this kind of maximization problem.)

Comment: The point is this: _You_ have to make this problem intersting to other users, not me. It is unlikely that users perform long computations before they decide to help you or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
Y = A k^a L^b;
PROF = P Y - r k - w L;
z1 = D[PROF, k];
z2 = D[PROF, L];
sol=Together[Simplify[Solve[{z1 == 0, z2 == 0}, {k, L}], {0 <= a <= 1 && 0 <= b <= 1 && a + b + c == 1 && A > 0 && k > 0 && L > 0 && P > 0 && r > 0 &&  w > 0 && PROF > 0}][[1]]]
{k, L} /. sol // FullSimplify
```

Comment: It's a bit nicer, imo, if we introduce another parameter `c` and add the assumption `a + b + c == 1` to `Simplify`. (+1)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Edited according to your hint. Thanks.